# Is it possible to define an "abstract" build in parent pom?

Tags: maven

I  want to define a build in the parent pom to enforce that build to the children.
Ideally a child pom just does mvn install and applies the build defined at the parent level.

I have 2 problems:

1. The build makes use of properties that are defined only in children
2. When I do mvn install on the parent I just want to create the pom and save it on my maven repo, not actually do a build (that should be done in children)
3. Is it possible to store helper files inside of the parent pom to use them in the child?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can define pretty much in the parent POM.

- You can define all the plugins in the pluginManagement. You can use the `<plugins>` section of the parent POM to activate the plugins without using them in the build of the POM itself (with `<phase>none</phase>` and `<inherited>false</inherited>` on the execution)
- You can build the parent POM and put it in a repository.
- You can predefine properties and let child POMs override them.

But you cannot add additional files.

Answer (score 0):

4all who stumbled upon this question only now (like me):

in addition to the possibilities described in the previous answer, you could define profiles in parent project, but activate them only in concrete project, e.g. by overriding profile activation property. This way you can avoid execution of the stuff during the build of the parent.

you could even go further and workaround limitation of additional files (beware, this is evil*):

- define helper module(s) in the repository of your parent project
- add dependency to the helper module in the profile defined in parent project
- unpack helper files using the maven-resources-plugin (copy-resources)

---

*) *why this is evil?* - well, if you need a hack like this, it is an indicator that something is wrong with your architecture. Otherwise, if this would be a common requirement, the Maven team would provide a proper way to handle it.